# How to specify C++11 with distutils?

Tags: python, c++11, distutils

I have a module that needs to be compiled with C++11. On GCC and Clang, that means a `std=c++11` switch, or `std=c++0x` on older compilers.

Python is not compiled with this switch so Distutils doesn't include it when compiling modules.

What is the preferred way to compile C++11 code with distutils?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `extra_compile_args` parameter of `distutils.core.Extension`:

```
ext = Extension('foo', sources=[....],
                libraries=[....], 
                extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
                ....)
```

Note that this is completely platform dependent. It won't even work on some older versions of gcc and clang.

Comment: I thought the whole point of distutils was to avoid "completely platform dependent". Since I'm distributing a library that needs to be compiled locally on the end user's machine, I really need something platform independent.

Comment: @Adam That is part of the point of `distutils`, but once it gets to compiling code natively this becomes complicated, so it gives you these handles to do platform specific stuff. You could do clever stuff in your `setup.py` to select the right platform specific stuff for a set of popular platforms. But there's no universal way of specifying C++11, and there are plenty of machines out there that don't have compilers that support it yet.

Comment: can you point me towards what that "clever stuff" would entail?

Comment: @Adam I would imagine using `os` or `sys` to find out which platform you're on, figure out what compiler it uses, then provide a map of compiler -> compiler options. Then set `extra_compile_args` using that information.

Comment: that's not clever, that's disheartening :P

Comment: @Adam It can be both :) At some point gcc and clang will be C++11 by default, but adoption can be very slow.

Comment: If you want to build this on windows via visual c++ it will just ignore the unknown options like "-std=c++11", still this is a little tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the default values for various Distutils compilation and link flags using environment variables.  This may require some experimentation depending on which platform you are on and how the Python you was using was built.  But generally overriding `CFLAGS` will affect the compilation phase and either one of `LDSHARED` or `LDFLAGS` will affect the link phase.

```
export CFLAGS='-std=c++11'
pip install blah
```

or

```
export CFLAGS='-std=c++11'
python setup.py install
```

On OS X, another option is to use the `ARCHFLAGS` environment variable which has the advantage of not wiping out the original `CFLAGS` or `LDSHARED` values.